# How can I change the color of the "Developer-PowerShell" in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I often use the "Developer-PowerShell" in Visual Studio. In Options under "Environment » Fonts and Color", if I select "Show settings for: Terminal" I can change the font that is used for the Developer-PowerShell. But I cannot change the color.

Is there a way to change the color, that is used by the Developer-PowerShell in Visual Studio? I assume, if I would select dark theme, that it would be dark then, but I don't want to generally use dark theme, I actually have a custom theme (in the custom theme I can set every color, but there too many, I have no idea, which one of the "whites" is the background for this window).

Comment: Does it not load the profile `$Profile`? There I think is the place for those changes.

Comment: Well it does load the $Profile, but I don't think that would be the right place for those changes. Here is why: usually (for windows default console windows) the colors are set up with the property of the window. That means, there are independent of the $Profile. The exact same thing happens in VS. here the background is white and text as black, instead of silver text on blue background. Without these things are setup in $Profile. I was also not able to usefully change the colors, with Console.SetForegroundColor() or similar methods.

Answer (score 0):

download Windows Terminal and customize it

I follow [this tut](https://dev.to/ansonh/customize-beautify-your-windows-terminal-2022-edition-541l) and it work for me in VS 2022, probably will work on VS 2019 [image: Customize & Beautify your terminal]